# Does wave function depend on frame of reference?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

I am aware of the Path integral approach to deriving the wave function where we figure out how it propogates through considering elementary amplitude contribution possible path to the total. However, would the calculation for wave function depend on what frame of reference we calculate it in or are all of them the same?